# Fleet Telematics Route Matching, query more attributes for each route link

Tags: here-api

I'm evaluating the Fleet Telematics Route Matching service and i'm trying to  retrieve more link attributes directly in the response. How can this be achieved?

I created a Freemium account on HERE.com and tried the basic example from the documentation: https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-match/topics/quick-start-gps-trace-route.html.
In the documentation of the service i found that it should be possible to get more attributes regarding the route links returned in the response: https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-match/topics/attributes-along-route.html

The following works (of course 123 is not my real app id, nor my real app code):

```
curl -v --request GET "https://rme.cit.api.here.com/2/matchroute.json?app_id=123&app_code=123&routemode=car&file=UEsDBBQAAAAIANmztEQSwaeZzwAAAM8BAAAQAAAAc2FtcGxlLXRyYWNlLmdweIXPTQuCMBwG8HufQnZv%2F605S0k9djEIungdZjpSJ27kPn6%2BRBgYXcYYv2cPzzG2deU8805L1YSIYoLiaHMsWvv9uBlYowOrZYhKY9oAoO973DOsugJ2hFBIz8k1K%2FNabGWjjWiy%2FJ36ShjVqqITd2lxpmo4XVKgMP6vZaCneKIyYabivzHnr4BhCbb6hoZRpnvMp86L%2BdIapxImRJxiSuh%2Bj5xq7CWY%2Bcz1EaypA10qxlfVjvOl8rxVxfzDQrk%2FFCfLRs7YpOCzA%2BZd49LoBVBLAQIUABQAAAAIANmztEQSwaeZzwAAAM8BAAAQAAAAAAAAAAEAIAAAAAAAAABzYW1wbGUtdHJhY2UuZ3B4UEsFBgAAAAABAAEAPgAAAP0AAAAAAA%3D%3D"
```

and returns:

```
{"RouteLinks":[{"linkId":25664478,"functionalClass":5,"confidence":1.0,"shape":"51.10168 0.39385 51.10184 0.39329","offset":0.62907,"mSecToReachLinkFromStart":2614,"linkLength":43.08},{"linkId":1022687683,"functionalClass":4,"confidence":1.0,"shape":"51.10184 0.39329 51.10214 0.39345","mSecToReachLinkFromStart":8376,"linkLength":35.21},{"linkId":1022687684,"functionalClass":4,"confidence":1.0,"shape":"51.10214 0.39345 51.10224 0.3935","mSecToReachLinkFromStart":10284,"linkLength":11.66},{"linkId":25664459,"functionalClass":4,"confidence":1.0,"shape":"51.10224 0.3935 51.10232 0.39354","mSecToReachLinkFromStart":11811,"linkLength":9.33},{"linkId":781742854,"functionalClass":4,"confidence":1.0,"shape":"51.10232 0.39354 51.10245 0.39361 51.10255 0.39367","mSecToReachLinkFromStart":16214,"linkLength":27.16},{"linkId":781742855,"functionalClass":4,"confidence":1.0,"shape":"51.10255 0.39367 51.10269 0.39376","mSecToReachLinkFromStart":16255,"linkLength":16.8},{"linkId":25664450,"functionalClass":4,"confidence":1.0,"shape":"51.10269 0.39376 51.10292 0.39391 51.10306 0.39401","mSecToReachLinkFromStart":19004,"linkLength":44.74},{"linkId":25664444,"functionalClass":4,"confidence":1.0,"shape":"51.10306 0.39401 51.10324 0.39413","mSecToReachLinkFromStart":29879,"linkLength":21.72},{"linkId":25664440,"functionalClass":4,"confidence":1.0,"shape":"51.10324 0.39413 51.10335 0.3942 51.1035 0.39431 51.1036 0.39439","mSecToReachLinkFromStart":37082,"linkLength":44.02},{"linkId":25664427,"functionalClass":4,"confidence":1.0,"shape":"51.1036 0.39439 51.10369 0.39446 51.10378 0.39453","mSecToReachLinkFromStart":40731,"linkLength":22.3},{"linkId":860272608,"functionalClass":4,"confidence":1.0,"shape":"51.10378 0.39453 51.10394 0.39465","mSecToReachLinkFromStart":43951,"linkLength":19.68},{"linkId":860272609,"functionalClass":4,"confidence":1.0,"shape":"51.10394 0.39465 51.10417 0.39482","mSecToReachLinkFromStart":44659,"linkLength":28.22},{"linkId":781742870,"functionalClass":4,"confidence":1.0,"shape":"51.10417 0.39482 51.10427 0.39489 51.10439 0.39497 51.10452 0.39505 51.10463 0.39512","mSecToReachLinkFromStart":48568,"linkLength":55.33},{"linkId":1022687692,"functionalClass":4,"confidence":1.0,"shape":"51.10463 0.39512 51.10483 0.39523","mSecToReachLinkFromStart":57622,"linkLength":23.55},{"linkId":1022687693,"functionalClass":4,"confidence":1.0,"shape":"51.10483 0.39523 51.10547 0.39554","offset":0.28475,"mSecToReachLinkFromStart":64944,"linkLength":74.44}],"TracePoints":[{"confidenceValue":1.0,"elevation":0.0,"headingDegreeNorthClockwise":10000.0,"headingMatched":-66.0,"lat":51.10177,"latMatched":51.10178,"linkIdMatched":25664478,"lon":0.39349,"lonMatched":0.3935,"matchDistance":1.46,"matchOffsetOnLink":0.6290743846692971,"minError":1.0,"routeLinkSeqNrMatched":0,"speedMps":0.0,"timestamp":0},{"confidenceValue":1.0,"elevation":0.0,"headingDegreeNorthClockwise":10000.0,"headingMatched":-66.0,"lat":51.10181,"latMatched":51.10182,"linkIdMatched":25664478,"lon":0.39335,"lonMatched":0.39336,"matchDistance":1.46,"matchOffsetOnLink":0.8790743846674338,"minError":1.0,"routeLinkSeqNrMatched":0,"speedMps":0.0,"timestamp":0},{"confidenceValue":1.0,"elevation":0.0,"headingDegreeNorthClockwise":10000.0,"headingMatched":22.0,"lat":51.10255,"latMatched":51.10255,"linkIdMatched":781742855,"lon":0.39366,"lonMatched":0.39367,"matchDistance":1.11,"matchOffsetOnLink":0.0,"minError":1.0,"routeLinkSeqNrMatched":5,"speedMps":0.0,"timestamp":0},{"confidenceValue":1.0,"elevation":0.0,"headingDegreeNorthClockwise":10000.0,"headingMatched":25.0,"lat":51.10398,"latMatched":51.10398,"linkIdMatched":860272609,"lon":0.39466,"lonMatched":0.39468,"matchDistance":1.87,"matchOffsetOnLink":0.1535150210712758,"minError":1.0,"routeLinkSeqNrMatched":11,"speedMps":0.0,"timestamp":0},{"confidenceValue":1.0,"elevation":0.0,"headingDegreeNorthClockwise":10000.0,"headingMatched":17.0,"lat":51.10501,"latMatched":51.10501,"linkIdMatched":1022687693,"lon":0.39533,"lonMatched":0.39532,"matchDistance":1.33,"matchOffsetOnLink":0.2847498087963734,"minError":1.0,"routeLinkSeqNrMatched":14,"* Connection #0 to host rme.cit.api.here.com left intact speedMps":0.0,"timestamp":0}],"Warnings":[],"MapVersion":"LATEST"}
```

However, my tries to get more attributes regarding the road links have not been successful so far. No matter which attributes i select, the following query does not work:

```
curl -v --request GET "https://rme.cit.api.here.com/2/matchroute.json?app_id=123&app_code=123&routemode=car&file=UEsDBBQAAAAIANmztEQSwaeZzwAAAM8BAAAQAAAAc2FtcGxlLXRyYWNlLmdweIXPTQuCMBwG8HufQnZv%2F605S0k9djEIungdZjpSJ27kPn6%2BRBgYXcYYv2cPzzG2deU8805L1YSIYoLiaHMsWvv9uBlYowOrZYhKY9oAoO973DOsugJ2hFBIz8k1K%2FNabGWjjWiy%2FJ36ShjVqqITd2lxpmo4XVKgMP6vZaCneKIyYabivzHnr4BhCbb6hoZRpnvMp86L%2BdIapxImRJxiSuh%2Bj5xq7CWY%2Bcz1EaypA10qxlfVjvOl8rxVxfzDQrk%2FFCfLRs7YpOCzA%2BZd49LoBVBLAQIUABQAAAAIANmztEQSwaeZzwAAAM8BAAAQAAAAAAAAAAEAIAAAAAAAAABzYW1wbGUtdHJhY2UuZ3B4UEsFBgAAAAABAAEAPgAAAP0AAAAAAA%3D%3D&attributes=LINK_ID"
```

and instead of a proper response, i just get

```
{"faultCode":"6a8a9966-b2eb-4a54-8f58-2f36e501bb94","responseCode":"400 Bad Request","message":"Invalid layer attribute parameter."}
```

Using a layer instead of an attributes does not work either:

```
curl -v --request GET "https://rme.cit.api.here.com/2/matchroute.json?app_id=123&app_code=123&routemode=car&file=UEsDBBQAAAAIANmztEQSwaeZzwAAAM8BAAAQAAAAc2FtcGxlLXRyYWNlLmdweIXPTQuCMBwG8HufQnZv%2F605S0k9djEIungdZjpSJ27kPn6%2BRBgYXcYYv2cPzzG2deU8805L1YSIYoLiaHMsWvv9uBlYowOrZYhKY9oAoO973DOsugJ2hFBIz8k1K%2FNabGWjjWiy%2FJ36ShjVqqITd2lxpmo4XVKgMP6vZaCneKIyYabivzHnr4BhCbb6hoZRpnvMp86L%2BdIapxImRJxiSuh%2Bj5xq7CWY%2Bcz1EaypA10qxlfVjvOl8rxVxfzDQrk%2FFCfLRs7YpOCzA%2BZd49LoBVBLAQIUABQAAAAIANmztEQSwaeZzwAAAM8BAAAQAAAAAAAAAAEAIAAAAAAAAABzYW1wbGUtdHJhY2UuZ3B4UEsFBgAAAAABAAEAPgAAAP0AAAAAAA%3D%3D&attributes=LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FC5"
```

This returns the same error as above.

Based on the documentation i would expect that there is some way to retrieve more link attributes directly in the response, but i cannot figure out how to do that. Obviously, i must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the following link

https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-match/topics/resource-matchroute-request.html

you can easily retrieve the attributes for the particular layers with the following command where the attributes parameter should be LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FCn(*). It is also possible to retrieve the particular information from these attributes with LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FCn(ISO_COUNTRY_CODE,RAMP,URBAN).

```
https://rme.cit.api.here.com/2/matchroute.json?app_id=123&app_code=123&routemode=car&file=UEsDBBQAAAAIANmztEQSwaeZzwAAAM8BAAAQAAAAc2FtcGxlLXRyYWNlLmdweIXPTQuCMBwG8HufQnZv%2F605S0k9djEIungdZjpSJ27kPn6%2BRBgYXcYYv2cPzzG2deU8805L1YSIYoLiaHMsWvv9uBlYowOrZYhKY9oAoO973DOsugJ2hFBIz8k1K%2FNabGWjjWiy%2FJ36ShjVqqITd2lxpmo4XVKgMP6vZaCneKIyYabivzHnr4BhCbb6hoZRpnvMp86L%2BdIapxImRJxiSuh%2Bj5xq7CWY%2Bcz1EaypA10qxlfVjvOl8rxVxfzDQrk%2FFCfLRs7YpOCzA%2BZd49LoBVBLAQIUABQAAAAIANmztEQSwaeZzwAAAM8BAAAQAAAAAAAAAAEAIAAAAAAAAABzYW1wbGUtdHJhY2UuZ3B4UEsFBgAAAAABAAEAPgAAAP0AAAAAAA%3D%3D&attributes=LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FCn(*)
```

Similarly, you can get the attributes for the other layers (i.e. ROAD_GEOM_FCn(*))

Hope this helps you.

Best Regards,

Jeyaprakash Rajagopal